# Using a template class as input to bind() in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, templates, wxwidgets

I have a set of wxPanels, pages to a notebook, for a GUI in C++.  They all have different data but a common set of functions for setting up are reading data.  I designed a helper class (my wording) to house all the common functions so each panel or frame does not need a cut and paste of essentially identical code.  The helper class is templated and called from inside the GUI panel class so that class can use those functions.  Everything seems to work with the exception of one item, the bind(event, method, handler) function in wxWidgets.  This is needed to bind a method in MyPanel to a button in MyPanel using the build GUI functions in MyHelperClass.  I've never posted code before so pardon the formatting, but here's a stripped down version of the basic functions/classes.

```
template<class T>
class MyHelperClass {

public:

    typedef void (T::*buttonPush)(wxCommandEvent & event);  //  This typedef seems to work 

    void makeSomeGUIpanels(pl, &pb, buttonPush f, &pp, *p);

private:

};


template<class T>
void MyHelperClass<T>::makeSomeGUIpanels(pl, &pb, buttonPush f, &pp, *p) {

    //  Do some stuff to set up the panels, buttons and labels.
    ...
    ...


    //  Bind each button to the input function.

    //  **** HERE IS THE PROBLEM.  ****  
    pb[0]->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, f, T);

    //  Put each panel together.
    enterBox->Add(pb[0]);
    pp[0]->SetSizer(enterBox);

}
```

I've cut out a lot of code that in my opinion is not relevant to the question, and removed the types in the function interface.  For example enterBox is defined in the function before use.  The use of the function occurs in each version of a Panel that is created.  An example is...

```
class MyPanel : public wxPanel
{
public:
    MyPanel(wxWindow *parent);

private:

    MyHelperClass<MyPanel> cpf;

    //  More stuff ...
}
```

The methods in cpf are invoked in this panel's methods to build the GUI.

```
void MyPanel::SomeFunction(){
    cpf.makeSomeGUIpanel(...);
}
```

Placing T in the bind function causes the compile error 'T': illegal use of this type as an expression.  I've tried using other approaches I've found on stack overflow for passing template into a function but none have worked.  Everything else does work so I think my template use is not horrible.  I've used templates before but never for anything like this.  I am not sure that the issue is a template syntax, it may be a wxWidgets issue with bind().  The method, f, needs to belong to the handler, in this case T, and I think that the compiler needs to be able to check this and maybe it cannot.  Note that the typedef I created in the class seems to work in the sense that it does not give an error when compiling or running with the bind command commented out.

I appreciate any help or insights.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `T` is a type, not an object.  You need `T{}` or `T()` to pass an object of type `T`.

Comment: Well then I need help with that.  I actually did try what you are suggesting and no better.  Why did it work in all other instances?

Comment: What happens when you use `T{}` or `T()`?

Comment: The error is no appropriate default constructor.  I would guess it's because of the dependence on (wxWindow *parent).  So if I get the correct format in the T(), perhaps with a second template type it should work.

Comment: Yes, if `T` is not default constructable then you'll need to provide parameters in the `{}`/`()` part.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: @NathanOliver, an interesting aside, the interface for bind requires the use of 'this'.  Not sure that works with templates.

Comment: @ggcg, the interface to bind does `not` require this. Where does this coming from?

Comment: I found it on a documentation site.  But I could have misinterpreted the statement, "Note that this pointer must be specified here."

Comment: @ggcg, this is completely wrong. Please read Vadim' reply in the ML. The third parameter to Bind() is an `event sink` - the object that handles the event, or IOW the object which references the event handler. Usually it is `this` pointer. But it can be any object.

Comment: @Igor, thanks.  That is how I interpreted it at first, but I misinterpreted the wording of that documentation

Comment: Too me it looks like you want to use the **panel** that you passed into your helper class/function as event handler. So perhaps something like ` pb[0]->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, f, p);` (if `p` is of type `MyPanel`)

Comment: @julians, that is exactly the idea.  But I'm having trouble getting the reference to MyPanel expressed using the template.

Comment: I am not sure if this has anything to do with templates. Think about how you would write `makeSomeGUIpanels` if you were to use concrete types instead of templates. I think the function signature should look something like this:
`MyHelperClass<T>::makeSomeGUIpanels(<other_params>*, T* panel)`